# text editors can't show directory

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Hello today I install Linux mint 20 and get problems with text editors, I'm not able to open specific directory (with text editors) which placed in `/var/www/html`, so when I try to find THAT directory from sublime text, last what I get is `/var/`, in addition I tried take and drop that folder in sublime, but it give me as file.

Comment: As a user can you `cd /var/www/html && ls -la` ? I sense some permission problems.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes, folder I've on user level

Comment: What text editor? Installed how? Some "snap"-installated applications cannot access files outside of your home directory.

Comment: @xenoid Sublime Text, installed from software manager

Comment: If your editor is sandboxed and can only access files within a sub-directory. Then you can use a bind mount, to re-mount part of the file-system into your directory. It will then appear in both places. (two addresses, like an alias ).